# UILabel added programmatically showing blur text on iphone 6

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview, uilabel

```
int dx = (int)CGRectGetMaxX(coverView.frame)+10;
int dy = (int)self.frame.size.width-CGRectGetMaxX(coverView.frame)-5;
titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(dx, padding,dy , 20)];
titleView.center = [self roundedCenterPoint:titleView.center];
[titleView setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
[titleView setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
[titleView setFont:[UIView yoda_fontWithType:YODA_FONT_TABLEVIEWCELL_TITLE]];
titleView.numberOfLines = 0;
titleView.opaque = YES;
titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

**then after creating it is added to UIatbleviewCell**

```
 [self addSubview:titleView];
```

**this method sets the text and through a category  on label frame is set**

```
 -(void) setTitle:(NSString*)title
{
    [titleView setText:title];
    [titleView setVerticalAlignmentTop];
}
```

**for rounding centre points**

```
-(CGPoint)roundedCenterPoint:(CGPoint) pt {
  return CGPointMake(round(pt.x), round(pt.y));
 }
```

**UIlabel Category method**

```
- (void) setVerticalAlignmentTop
{
     CGSize textSize = [self.text sizeWithFont:self.font
                        constrainedToSize:self.frame.size
                            lineBreakMode:self.lineBreakMode];

    CGRect textRect = CGRectMake(self.frame.origin.x,
                             self.frame.origin.y,
                             self.frame.size.width,
                             ceilf(textSize.height));

    [self setFrame:CGRectIntegral(textRect)];
    [self setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Comment: what is yoda_fontWithType ??

Comment: just a category on UIView which returns font

Comment: can u pls show me the frame value of the titleview label

Comment: Can u give the value of titleview frame

Comment: when I logged the value just after initialising it shows x=100.500000,y=10.000000,w=225.000000,h=20.000000 and after setting setVerticalAlignmentTop it shows x=100.000000,y=10.000000,w=226.000000,h=22.000000

Comment: solved it, it was'nt anything in the code..my app was scalling on iphone 6

Answer (score 1):

First in this line

```
titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

add `UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight` like this

```
titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```

Second increase height of label like currently you are setting 20 make it 30 and check.

Comment: I removed the line titleView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth; but still the text is not as sharp as it looks on iphone 5 and 4s

Answer (score 0):

Its because the `titleView` frame is using floating numbers.

To force integers value for your frame just insert the following line of code:

```
[titleView setFrame:CGRectIntegral(titleView.frame)];
```

after the line

```
titleView = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(dx, padding,dy , 20)];
```

Comment: I'm already using it in the category  `[self setFrame:CGRectIntegral(textRect)];`

Comment: I think you have to call the category method before setting the center